# Low-cost mutlifunction printer/scanner that can perform 2-sided scans

Tags: printer, scanner

Can anyone recommend a low-cost multifunction printer/scanner that can perform 2-sided scans (aka double-sided or duplex scans)?

- Can include a laser or inkjet printer.
- Sheet-fed scanner is preferred, but not required.  Please specify in your answer if it has a sheet-fed scanner.  I'm thinking the only way to have 2-sided scanning would be sheet-fed, but I'm happy to be proven wrong!
- WiFi access is required.
- Fax is not needed.  Only printing and scanning functions are required.
- Preferred cost should be under $150 (sale price is fine).

Comment: before we help, have you done any searches on your own through Newegg, or any of the major printer companies such as:  Epson, Brother, HP?

Comment: @NZKshatriya Yes. So far, I have found the Brother MFC-J480DW as a possibility, but I am finding conflicting information on whether or not it can perform 2-sided scans from its sheet feeder.

Comment: BTW, here is the manual for that Brother device. Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but it does not seem to specify whether or not it performs 2-sided scans from the sheet feeder: http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_mfc880dw/uke/manual/index.html

Comment: Your budget of under $150 is not going to cut it for two sided scanning in a printer, or even a stand alone scanner.   The least expensive I can find is in the $500+ range via HP.com.

Comment: @NZKshatriya No offense, but you are completely wrong.  There are quite a few multifunction devices for $250-$400 that offer two-sided scanning.  Please move on; I don't think you can help for this question.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard  I was referring to your desired sheet fed dual sided printing.  And you yourself set the budget at under $150.   Hence my official answer to this question.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard  Also, I found the correct search term, Duplex Scanning.

Comment: Are you looking for duplex scanning, or duplex copy, duplex scan/print.

Comment: The Brother MFC-L2740DW is $180 at [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MRAU8OE?tag=price106730d-20&ascsubtag=227883102&m=ATVPDKIKX0DER). Cheaper models I've found are duplex for print only.

Comment: @Alpha3031  That was the same thing I found after searching around.  His budget needs to be adjusted just a little, else he is not going to find what he is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to adjust your price slightly, I recommend the [HP OfficeJet Pro 8720](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CJNMMZG). It won [The Wirecutter's](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-all-in-one-printer/) best all in one printer recommendation in September 2016.

[image: HP OfficeJet Pro 8720]

Among the many features listed on Amazon:

> Fast two-sided copying and scanning: Breeze through multipage documents with one-pass two-sided scanning and a 50-page automatic document feeder.

Now, the downside: Normally this is a $300 machine. It is currently on sale on Amazon for $165. It's slightly above budget, but I believe it's worth the extra $15.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Do you happen to have any experience with this device?  I've read in several places that HP inkjets are known for making noises at random times (probably cleaning the heads or something like that).  Any idea if this one has the same issue?  BTW, aesthetically, HP did a great job on this device! :)

Answer (score 1):

After further research using the correct search terms (and digging deeper on each device as neither Amazon or Newegg are that good at listing all relevant information, I have come up with this one.

[Epson WorkForce WF-3620 WiFi Direct All-in-One Color Inkjet Printer, Copier, Scanner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXLGF06)  $83.07 @ Amazon.com

Has everything you asked for, and is under budget.